# How can I use an allocator with std::set?

Tags: c++, set, c++14, c++17, allocator

I am trying to use my own allocator to measure memory usage in a C++ `std::set`. Unfortunately, I am getting errors at link time. In an effort to simplify the problem, I have the following program:

```
#include<set>
#include<vector>
#include<memory>
//using Container = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>;
using Container = std::set<int, std::allocator<int>>;

int main() {
  Container container;
  container.push_back(4711);
  container.insert(4711);  
  return 0;
}
```

Results can be found in wandbox https://wandbox.org/permlink/R5WcgSvSWiqstYxL#wandbox-resultwindow-code-body-1

I have tried both gcc 6.3.0, gcc 7.1.0, clang 4.0.0 and clang 6.0.0HEAD. In all cases, I get errors when I use a `std::set`, but not when I use a `std::vector`.

How can I declare my set to use an allocator?

I want to use C++17, but answers in C++14 are fine too.

Comment: That's available since c++98 standards, why the c++14, c++1z tags?

Comment: Because I'm lucky enough to be writing code for gcc 7.1 with C++17 flags turned on! The code examples I have seen with custom allocators often uses deprecated calls. I wanted to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should look at the template parameters of [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) more closely:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

When you write: `std::set<int, std::allocator<int>>` you are saying that you want to use an allocator to compare the keys. That doesn't make any sense, and because an allocator is not callable like a comparator, the compiler complains.

You'll need to explicitly provide the `Compare` parameter:

```
using Container = std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int>>;
```

Comment: Oh, I'm such an idiot. Thanks for the answer. Works perfectly.
Another reason why we need concepts!